# Can't get mysql/phpmyadmin to work after updating to 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

After the update, mysql/phpmyadmin stopped working. When I do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing the database:                            
 │                                                                             
 │ mysql: [Warning] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified. Will throw an     
 │ error in future versions ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user         
 │ 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) .
```

The way I see it, I need to specify the port in some config file but I don't know where?

Comment: Do you have set the `port` variable in `my.cnf`? See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_port

Answer (score 8):

My machine configuration
- Ubuntu 16.04
- MySql 5.7.13
- PHP 7.0.8
- Apache 2.4.18

Edit the file /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf, changing

`dbc_dbport=''` to `dbc_dbport='0'`

After edit the file and save it, if you are still on the dbconfig-common wizard select **retry**, if not run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` (choose **Yes** when ask you if you want to Reinstall database for phpmyadmin), and continue normally without change any value, if you want change some value, do it in the file that you edit before.

When configuration window asks what you want to do with existing configuration file, choose **Keep the local version currently installed**.

In this point you can check the differences and only must exist the ones that you made in the file.

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: After trying this, I get: `mysql said: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`  -- Tried with both random password and madeup one. Had to finally 'apt purge  phpmyadmin' and run 'apt autoremove' on dbconfig etc. Then reinstall using defaults/random password. Worked. No dbcport change needed. This error occurred for me after a `do-release-upgrade` 14>16

Answer (score 2):

Following a `do-release-upgrade` (14 to 16), I had the same issue.
I had to do the following:

Remove and clean out installation as much as possible:

```
sudo apt remove phpmyadmin && sudo apt purge phpmyadmin
```

Removing phpmyadmin should have left orphaned packages on most systems - remove them.
Specifically: 'dbconfig-common' & 'dbconfig-mysql':

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Now you need to install it all again - (use defaults/hit enter):

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

I could immediately login to the phpmyadmin local web page. Working again.
Note: `apt-get` may be used in place of `apt` above.
Note: `dbc_dbport=''` was unchanged. I didn't touch it as per other answer.

Comment: Also remember to do database deconf when prompted.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.0/+bug/1447808/comments/6

You could succeed your installation by choosing mysql-user `root` instead of `phpmyadmin` and `debian-sys-maint`

After this you need to create mysql-user like `root`

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```